# R H2o Deep learning CURL error: Timeout was reached

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o, rcurl, h2o.ai

I am running a H2o deep learning model in R (binary classification) using the following grid search code

```r
hyper_params <- list(
    activation = c("Rectifier", "Maxout", "Tanh", "RectifierWithDropout", "MaxoutWithDropout", "TanhWithDropout"),
    hidden = list(c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5), c(10, 10, 10, 10), c(50, 50, 50), c(100, 100, 100)),
    epochs = c(50, 100, 200),
    l1 = c(0, 0.00001, 0.0001),
    l2 = c(0, 0.00001, 0.0001),
    rate = c(0, 01, 0.005, 0.001),
    rate_annealing = c(1e-8, 1e-7, 1e-6),
    rho = c(0.9, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999),
    epsilon = c(1e-10, 1e-8, 1e-6, 1e-4),
    momentum_start = c(0, 0.5),
    momentum_stable = c(0.99, 0.5, 0),
    input_dropout_ratio = c(0, 0.1, 0.2),
    max_w2 = c(10, 100, 1000, 3.4028235e+38)
)
search_criteria <- list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete",
                                                max_models = 100,
                                                max_runtime_secs = 12000,
                                                stopping_tolerance = 0.001,
                                                stopping_rounds = 15,
                                                seed = 42)
dl_grid <- h2o.grid(algorithm = "deeplearning",
                                        x = x,
                                        y = y,
                                        grid_id = "dl_grid",
                                        training_frame = df,
                                        validation_frame = tst,
                                        nfolds = 25,                          
                                        fold_assignment = "Stratified",
                                        hyper_params = hyper_params,
                                        search_criteria = search_criteria,
                                        seed = 42
)
```

However I am getting the error

> "na .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = urlSuffix, : Unexpected CURL error: Timeout was reached: [localhost:54321] Resolving timed out after 10180 milliseconds [1] "Job request failed Unexpected CURL error: Timeout was reached: [localhost:54321] Resolving timed out after 10180 milliseconds, will retry after 3s."

My R version details are

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
crt            ucrt
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          4
minor          2.0
year           2022
month          04
day            22
svn rev        82229
language       R
version.string R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
nickname       Vigorous Calisthenics****